# Practical to use snippets as search suggest?

Tags: java, marklogic, marklogic-8

I am trying to implement type-ahead in my app, and I got search suggest to work with an element range index as recommended in the documentation. The problem is, it doesn't fit my use case.

As anyone who has used it knows, it will not return results unless the search string is at the beginning of the content being searched. Barring the use of a leading and trailing wildcard, this won't return what I need.

I was thinking instead of simply doing a search based on the term, then returning the result snippets (truncated in my server-side code) as the suggestions in my type-ahead.

As I don't have a good way of comparing performance, I was hoping for some insight on whether this would be practical, or if it would be too slow.

Also, since it may come up in the answers, yes I have read the post about "chunked Element Range Indexes", but being new to MarkLogic, I can't make heads or tails of it and haven't been able to adapt it to my app.

Comment: Are you using the OOTB Client API, or are you building your own services? Sounds like you're using Client API...

Comment: Yes, I am using the Java API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the Chunked Element Range Indexes blog post, and found out last-minute that my performance numbers were skewed by a surprisingly large document in my index.  When I removed that large document, many of the other techniques such as wildcard matching were suddenly much faster.  That surprised me because all the other search engines I'd used couldn't offer such fast performance and flexibility for type-ahead scenarios, expecially if I tried introducing a wild-card search.  I decided not to push my post publicly, but someone else accidentally did it for me, so we decided to leave it out there since it still presents a valid option.

Since MarkLogic offers multiple wildcard indexes, there's really a lot you can do in that area.  However, search snippets would not be the right way to do that as I believe they'd add some overhead.  Call cts:search or one of the other cts calls to match a lexicon.  I'm guessing you'd want cts:element-value-match.  That does wildcard matches against a range index since which are all in memory, so faster.  Turn on all your wildcard indexes on your db if you can.

It should be called from a custom XQuery script in a MarkLogic HTTP server.  I'm not recommending a REST extension as I usually would, because you need to be as stream-lined as possible to do most type-ahead scenarios correctly (that is, fast enough).

I'd suggest you find ways to whittle down the set of values in the range index to less than 100,000 so there's less to match against and you're not letting in any junk suggestions.  Also, make sure that you filter the set of matches based on the rest of the query (if a user already started typing other words or phrases).  Make sure your HTTP script limits the number of suggestions returned since a user can't usually benefit from a long list of suggestions.  And craft some algorithms to rank the suggestions so the most helpful ones make it to the top.  Finally, be very, very careful not to present suggestions that are more distracting than helpful.  If you're going to give your users type-ahead, it will interrupt their searching and train-of-thought, so don't interrupt them if you're going to suggest search phrases that won't help them get what they want. I've seen that way too often, even on major websites.  Don't do type-ahead unless you're willing to measure the usage of the feature, and tune it over time or remove it if it's distracting users.

Hoping that helps!

Comment: Thanks, that gives me some things to consider! On a side note, I hope it's ok, but I sent you a LinkedIn request. We share Alma mater and I work for one of your former employers.

Answer (score 1):

You mention you are using a range index to populate your suggestions, but you can use word lexicons as well. Word lexicons would produce suggestions based on tokenized character data, not entire values of elements (or json properties). It might be worth looking into that.

Alternatively, since you are mentioning wildcards, perhaps [`cts:value-match`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:value-match) could be of interest to you. It runs on values (not words) from range indexes, but takes a wild-carded expression as input. It would perform far better than a snippet approach, which would need to pull up and process actual contents.

HTH!

Comment: Ya, I have used a word lexicon, and it works just fine to generate words, but it won't necessarily generate a meaningful phrase that would appear in a document. Is there any way to use it in phrases?

I have tried out value-match in the query console and it runs into the same problem of needing a leading and trailing wildcard, which I understand leads to significant performance hits.

Comment: @fun_hat Phrase generation is more of a NLP problem, and I don't think anything in ML will do that for you out of the box. You could use one of the free, open-source NLP libraries to generate phrases or ngrams, ingest them into ML, and use an index on those values to supply search suggestions. That would not be a small project, however.

Comment: @fun_hat, it sounds like you're ok with matching phrases from an element, you don't need NLP to pull phrases out of plain text, right?

Comment: @fun_hat: Regarding performance hit: i'd measure first. I'm confident value-match will always outperform a snippet approach. Also consider sending back only the top 10 or 20 with each round-trip, to save band-width. The suggestions will automatically improve as more characters are typed, and you can't really show 100's of suggestions on screen in a useful way anyhow..